# Pandas read_sql with placeholders. 'Where cause' an error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

Here is MS Access [database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dzXDdWuHsq7rxLZMl1HCIQuSAeIwVRd7), it contains a table. I'd like to read it into DataFrame. The issue here is when 
"WHERE" is used it causes **pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)**

```
import pyodbc #conda install -c anaconda pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
db_path=os.path.realpath("test01.accdb")
conn_str = (
    r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    f"DBQ={db_path};"
    )

#sql_str='''SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1''' # << this one works    
sql_str='''SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.Column01)="DDD"))''' # << this one doesn't work

with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as conn:    
    df=pd.read_sql(sql_str, conn)
print(df.head())
```

Database:

Column01    Column02
AAA BBB
CCC DDD
УУУ ГГГ

Comment: I don't think it changes anything but can you try with the same query without the parenthesis: `sql_str='SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Column01="DDD"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah solved it. This is my solution:

```
import pyodbc #conda install -c anaconda pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import os
db_path=os.path.realpath("test01.accdb")
conn_str = (
    r"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};"
    f"DBQ={db_path};"
    )
sql_str='''SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Column01=?'''

with pyodbc.connect(conn_str) as conn:    
    df=pd.read_sql(sql_str, conn, params=("CCC",))
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, try it without the parentheses:

```
sql_str = '''SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.Column01 = "DDD"'''
```

However, if you're ever using a variable, it is best to use placeholders to validate your data against the column type in the `WHERE` clause and avoid possible SQL injection. Good luck!

Comment: Whether or not to use a placeholder depends on whether or not "DDD" is user-provided data.  If it's a static literal, there's no need for a placeholder.  It's good practice, though, to use ANSI standard literals: in SQL, a literal string uses single quotes.  Double quotes signify identifiers.  The above query should produce an error: *no such column: DDD*.